# Android: Widget onReceive() not getting called

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, broadcastreceiver

I have a widget whose layout has an imageView. The view needs to be changed based on some activity. So, whenever that happens, I am calling a `sendBroadcast()` with the action set to `UPDATE_WIDGET`. However, the `onReceive()` in the widget code is not getting called. Below is my code.

```
public class TaskWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "widget update", 2000).show();
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.searchwidget);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UPDATE_WIDGET)) {
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.newImage, R.drawable.Pic1);
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

In the manifest,

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.rahul.testwidget.TaskWidget"
    android:label="Task Widget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="com.rahul.UPDATE_WIDGET" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to update your widget layout 
use this code just befor `super.onReceive(context, intent);`

```
ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, SimpleWidget.class);
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widget, views);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your action name must be `com.rahul.UPDATE_WIDGET` instead of `UPDATE_WIDGET`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the broadcast from a listener on your widget you need to create a PendingIntent for a Broadcast.

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Also, you don't seem to be able to attach 2 pending intents to a button in the widget.